# How to handle displaying of datetimes when users are in different timezones?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I am creating a social networking type website. The website is doing great in regards to traffic etc. I have come across a problem where there is a live news feed of peoples statuses and interactions. When I post something from here (Atlanta GA), is states it was posted under 1 minute ago. To people in Australia, it says it was posted 16hrs ago.

I am using a LAMP setup, with php 5. As far as the JQuery plug im using timeago to make the abbr's look pretty.

I am not sure if I need to be setting the PHP timezone for users based on their location, or the DB timezone based on their location.

Comment: I must add, the PHP server and MySQL server are both setup in EST timezone. Also I am using a datetime NOW() when entering data.

Comment: Usually it's best to store dates in the DB in UTC, and then convert as appropriate in your code. Having a fixed timezone to source data from solves a lot of portability problems (e.g. having to update all date/time fields should you move to another host in a different timezone).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have all of the dates be kept in something like UTC and do the comparisons based on that that. If you need to display a date just transform it from UTC into whatever timezone a specific user is in (either on your server or via JS).

Answer (score 0):

The timeago plug-in expects an input of UTC time or browser local time.  You are probably giving timeago a local time marked as UTC.  Here's an example assuming local time of 9:25 AM:

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();});
</script>

Correct UTC: <abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-25T13:25:00Z">March 25, 2011</abbr>
Correct Local: <abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-25T09:25:00">March 25, 2011</abbr>
Wrong (local time marked as UTC)<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-25T09:25:00Z">March 25, 2011</abbr>
```

Don't worry about changing the DB timezone or PHP.  Do it in Javascript.  Figure out if the time string that PHP is sending to the browser is already converted to UTC.  If it is, add the 'Z' suffix to the timestring before you call timeago.  If it is not UTC, remove the 'Z' suffix.  Hope that helps.